# In C#, What is the best way to aggregate and transform one DateTime collection into another?

Tags: c#, datetime, collections

I have a little calendar tool in C# and I am trying to figure out how to do a conversion from one array of DateTime objects to another.  Here are the details:

I start off with collection of DateTime object

```
 IEnumerable<DateTime> slots = GetSlots();
```

where each DateTime represents that starting time of an available slot (think open slot in calendar) **All slots are for 30 minutes** This is a given.  So for example:

```
var slots = new List<DateTime>()

slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(5,00, 0));

slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(9,00, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(9,30, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(10,00, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(10,30, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(11,00, 0));
slots.Add(DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(16,30, 0));
```

in the above example, it means i am free:

1. From 5:00 - 5:30
2. From 9:00 - 9:30
3. From 9:30 - 10:00
4. From 10:00 - 10:30
5. From 10:30 - 11:00
6. From 11:00 - 11:30
7. From 4:30 - 5:00

because i take the time from the item in the collection as the start time and simply add 30 minutes to it and that is considered a free slot.

I now have the requirement to take a larger time window (lets use 2 hours) and find out how many 2 hour slots free i have so  I now need to take this array of dates and "merge" into into bigger buckets. Given the bigger bucket is 2 hours (120 minutes), I want a function like this

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> aggregateArray = MergeIntoLargerSlots(slots, 120);
```

I would basically have to loop through the slots array above and "merge" items that are lined up next to each out to make bigger buckets.  If any of the merged items is 2 hours long then that should show up as an entry in the resulting array.  Using the example above the resulting aggregateArray would have 2 items in the collection it that would have the times:

- 9AM (because i have a free slot from 9-11 AM (120 mins).
- 9:30AM (because i have a free slot from 9:30-11:30 AM (120 mins).

*NOTE:* 30 minutes "chunks" are the smallest interval so DON'T need to include 9:05 to 11:05 as an example

So given the previous array I have two 2 hour windows of time free in the day

I am struggling to figure out how this MergeIntoLargerSlots function would work so i would hoping to get some suggestion for how to approach this problem.

Comment: Are you saying that if you find 4 consecutive half hour slots, you want to replace them with a single two hour slot?

Comment: Why wouldn't the final array also contain 9:01, 9:02,... 9:29? Are the 30 minute chunks the smallest possible?

Comment: On a side note, you're writing more code than you need to. I recommend this pattern: `DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(9, 0, 0)`

Comment: @Luka Horvat - good question - less assume 30 minute chunks are the smallest interval.  I updated the question to highlight this point and make it explicit

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw - thanks . . i updated the question to make it simpler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only works for half hour intervals, you can figure out to make it work for others if you need to.

```
public List<DateTime> MergeIntoLargerSlots(List<DateTime> slots, int minutes)
{
     int count = minutes/30;
     List<DateTime> retVal = new List<DateTime>();
     foreach (DateTime slot in slots)
     {
          DateTime end = slot.AddMinutes(minutes);
          if (slots.Where(x => x >= slot && x < end).Count() == count)
          {
              retVal.Add(slot);
          }
     }
     return retVal;   
}
```

Here's a brief explanation of my problem solving approach; I take in the minutes and the slots list. I add minutes to get an end time which gives me range. From there, I use the `Where` operator to produce and `IEnumerable<DateTime>` from `slots` that has the slots in that range. I compare the result to the `count` variable I got from doing `minutes/slotLength` if the numbers match then you have the necessary slots. With your sample data the result of the `Where` for 9 AM would have 4 values in it; 9, 9:30, 10 and 10:30, ofc the count is 4, 120/30 == 4, so that gets added to `retVal`. The same would be true for 9:30, no other times would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your original list is sorted (if it is not, make it so it is), you could loop through your original list and check whether adjacent items are consecutive (i.e. whether the start times have a distance of exactly 30 minutes). Always keep track of the first item in the current series of consecutive timeslots - once you reach four of them (with 4 consecutive 30 minutes timeslots adding up to a possible two-hour timeslot; other timeslot sizes obviously require different factors), save a new two-hour timeslot into your resulting list and update your reference to the beginning of the current series of consecutive items.

Untested, so please consider this as pseudocode:

```
var twoHourSlots = new List<DateTime>();
int consecutiveSlotsCount = 0;
DateTime? previousSlot;
foreach (DateTime smallSlotStart in slots) {
    if (previousSlot.HasValue) {
        if (smallSlotStart - previousSlot.Value == new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)) {
            consecutiveSlotsCount++;
        } else {
            consecutiveSlotsCount = 0;
        }
    }
    if (consecutiveSlotsCount == 4) {
        twoHourSlots.Add(smallSlotStart - new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0));
        consecutiveSlots = 0;
        previousSlot = null;
    } else {
        previousSlot = smallSlotStart;
    }
}
```

Some things to note:

- I am using arithmetic operators on `DateTime` values. Check the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986512%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find out more; they do handy things and often let you work with [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values automatically.
- I am using a [`TimeSpan` constructor that takes hours, minutes and seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) several times. So that's what the three numbers mean.
- I have declared `previousSlot`, a variable that keeps track of the last slot looked at (to compare to the current one), as `DateTime?` (again, check the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are not sure what a nullable type is). That is because in the first iteration of the `foreach` loop, there is no previous slot to look at and the loop has to behave differently.
- Likewise, `previousSlot` is set to `null` when we have found a 2-hour slot, as the last 30-minute slot of the found 2-hour slot should not be counted to the next possible 2-hour slot.
- Once four consecutive 30-minute slots have been found, one hour and thirty minutes are subtracted from the beginning of the last one. That is because the thirty minutes after the beginning of the last 30-minute slot will be part of the resulting 2-hour slot.

Answer (score 0):

Evan beat me to and did it with one less loop, but here was my solution:

```
    private List<DateTime> MergeArray(List<DateTime> slots, int minutes)
    {
        var segments = minutes / InitialSegment;
        var validSegments = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (var slot in slots.OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            var validSegment = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < segments-1; i++)  
            {
                var next = slot.AddMinutes(InitialSegment * (i + 1));
                if (slots.All(x => x != next))
                {
                    validSegment = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (validSegment)
                validSegments.Add(slot);
        }
        return validSegments;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, Evan's response uses two loops, as well - it's just that one of them is hidden in the `Where` call ;-)

Comment: Whoops, I typed too fast - with your call to `All`, you actually make up for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `TimeInterval` class since there are a lot of other interesting things you can do with it.

```
public sealed class TimeInterval
{
    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get { return Start.AddMinutes(Duration); } }
    public double Duration { get; private set; }

    public TimeInterval(DateTime start, int duration)
    {
        Start = start;
        Duration = duration;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimeInterval> Merge(TimeInterval that)
    {
        if(that.Start >= this.Start && that.Start <= this.End)
        {
            if(that.End > this.End)
                Duration += (that.Duration - (this.End - that.Start).TotalMinutes);

            yield return this;
        }
        else
        {       
            yield return this;
            yield return that;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an O(n) merge algorithm that will work for intervals of arbitrary sizes (in minutes).

```
//the `spans` parameter must be presorted
public IEnumerable<TimeInterval> Merge(IEnumerable<TimeInterval> spans, int duration)
{
    var stack = new Stack<TimeInterval>();

    stack.Push(spans.First());

    foreach (var span in spans.Skip(1))
        foreach(var interval in stack.Pop().Merge(span)) //this enumeration is guaranteed to have either one element or two elements.
            stack.Push(interval);

    return from interval in stack where interval.Duration >= duration select interval;
}
```